# Replaced bad ballast and maginfying light still won't work

Tags: light-fixture, ballast

I have a LUXO Magnifying lamp that after years the ballast finally went bad, checked the coil and it was open. Ordered one from Luxo same kind and specs, hooked it up and nothing, not even a hum. Maybe the miniature starter hard wired to the ballast is bad? I checked the old one and got 2 ohms connected, haven't checked the new one yet. I don't believe there is any polarity involved in hooking up these simple 2 wire ballasts, am I wrong? Maybe I just got a bad ballast from them. Checked it and got 23 ohms with starter connected but, I have no idea if that's what I should get. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, small appliance repair is off-topic here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small appliance repair is off-topic here.

Comment: And yet, we often cover ballasts in hardwired lamps. OP can you post photos of the labels on both ballasts?

Comment: A little conflicting comments, sorry but, I can't answer one without going against the other so I'll just step quietly out of here.

Comment: No, just edt in your photo before the close-happy get their way. A lamp is not a freaking appliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a starter I would replace that it is more common to have those go bad than the ballast, the starter provides the strike voltage to initiate the plasma in the tube, the ballast or inductor is to limit the current once the lamp strikes and the internal lamp resistance drops.

Comment: Your right sir, I'll check the starter in the new one and see if it's any good and if not I'll swap starters.Thx again!